# Understanding complexity of deleting duplicates from a linked-list

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, time-complexity

I have written this program to delete duplicate nodes from an unsorted linked list:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/* A linked list node */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

// Utility function to create a new Node
struct Node *newNode(int data)
{
   Node *temp = new Node;
   temp->data = data;
   temp->next = NULL;
   return temp;
}

/* Function to remove duplicates from a
   unsorted linked list */
void removeDuplicates(struct Node *start)
{
    // Hash to store seen values
    unordered_set<int> seen;

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    struct Node *curr = start;
    struct Node *prev = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        // If current value is seen before
        if (seen.find(curr->data) != seen.end())
        {
           prev->next = curr->next;
           delete (curr);
        }
        else
        {
           seen.insert(curr->data);
           prev = curr;
        }
        curr = prev->next;
    }
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    /* The constructed linked list is:
     10->12->11->11->12->11->10*/
    struct Node *start = newNode(10);
    start->next = newNode(12);
    start->next->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next->next = newNode(12);
    start->next->next->next->next->next =
                                    newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next->next->next->next =
                                    newNode(10);

    printf("Linked list before removing duplicates : \n");
    printList(start);

    removeDuplicates(start);

    printf("\nLinked list after removing duplicates : \n");
    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Does finding each element in the hash table affect the complexity? If yes what should be the time complexity of this algorithm considering that the set is implemented as a Binary Search tree where the cost of searching an element is O(logn) in worst case.
According to me T(n)=T(n-1)+log(n-1) ie. the nth element will perform log(n-1) comparisons (ie the height of tree with n-1 elements)
Please give a mathematical analysis.

Comment: That depends if your hash table has many collisions or not, generally there is few so it would probably be O(1) and hence not affect the complexity.

Comment: Well, [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) actually has constant time complexity (on average) so that is O(1).

Comment: Approach shared by you is as efficient as it gets, as you need to traverse the list atleast once O(N), to delete the duplicate, using set or unordered set won't affect the overall time as both of these will be  O(log(N)) and O(1) respectively for lookup.

Comment: @AmitKumar In worst case for N elements the total cost for lookup will become N*O(logN) .That would definitely affect complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does finding each element in the hash table affect the complexity?

Well, in your code you are using [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) which has an average complexity of O(1), so the simple answer is - No.

> ...considering that the set is implemented as a Binary Search tree where the cost of searching an element is O(logn) in worst case.

Again, you have chosen `unordered_set` which is not a binary search. I believe some of the implementation of `set` use Red/Black trees and you would be looking at O(logN), but with the `unordered_set` it should be constant time.  So now the only issue is the traversal of your linked list.  Which, since you are just walking it in one direction while visiting each node, is an O(N) operation.

Comment: What if I had used set instead of unordered_set. How would that have affected the complexity?

Comment: @abhishekgupta - I already answered that. With `std::set` you are looking at O(logN) rather than O(1) amortized. You still have to walk your list which is O(N) and the set lookup is O(logN).